# IE10: CSS :after assignment does not get interpreted

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have created a CSS rule that's being applied to a `SPAN` element residing within a `TD` element.

The rule is supposed to add content to the span. I'm using the `:after` selector for doing this.

So far so good. IE8 displays everything correctly. But with my IE10 I don't see the content added to the `SPAN` element.

Using Internet Explorer Development Tools (F12), I can see that both rules have been disabled by IE10:

[image]

What's causing this to happen? Why are these rules disabled? There are no overriding substitution rules defined in the stylesheet to do this.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: how about !important?

Comment: !important doesn't work as I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inserted elements are inline by default. Try setting it to inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today with IE10 with an :after setting for an image. Turns out I had two errors; I didn't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the file, and in Compatibility View Settings the `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View` option was checked. After I fixed my webpage and unchecked the value the page displayed as expected.

Here is the css I am using:

```
.foo:after {
    content: url(images/foo.png);
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 8px;
}
```